# Will a function in an if statement only be read if the statement is true?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

If I put a function into an if statement is this an effective way to 'declare only if not yet declared'? I read on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631535/php-function-inside-function) that functions nested inside others worked the same as non-nested (not sure this applies here). Will my function always execute or only when if is true?

```
  if(!function_exists('myFunction')){
    //Add myFunction just in case it wasn't declared previously
    function myFunction() { 
    // do something
    }  
    myFunction();
  }
  else {
    myFunction();
  }
```

Alternatively, is there a better way to do this, being that the function may or may not be previously declared in a parent file?

Comment: place function myFunction(){} outside of the if statement if you plan to call it elsewhere (like in your else statement)

Comment: I plan for it to be previously declared elsewhere, this is just a fallback. So this works then? (without double-declaring it)

Comment: this is a fallback for the function not existing somewhere in the same document? unless ur dynamically creating this function, thats ridiculous. but yes, this will work.

Comment: Why not test it out?  Run this code and see what happens.  Then declare `myFunction` outside the `if` and see what happens.

Comment: No. This document is just a bunch of functions. I include this document from other programs. As I need a function I used on one of the programs, I don't want to re-declare it, but I also don't want it to break in the future should I call it from a different program

Comment: @RocketHazmat I intended for it to be a simple yes/no. Don't have php installed atm...

Comment: You can test it using an online codepad, like http://codepad.org/

Comment: Thanks both. Wasn't aware of codepad. We should close as @LifeInTheGrey answered the question. If you want to put in an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: added as answer ... easiest answer ive done :D

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey Yeah it got dragged out more than intended. I kinda expected someone would share a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place function myFunction(){} outside of the if statement if you plan to call it elsewhere (like in your else statement)