# How to make a PHP function work inside a CodeIgniter function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `CodeIgniter` function and inside it I have a `PHP` function. I can't get this `PHP` function to work. Please see the code below. The parameter of `acmazdami($parameter)` function is an array. Maybe it is something to do with that. Can anyone help. Best Regards and thank you in advance...

```
  public function pozisyon_tutma() {// CI function
    function acmazdami($parametre){//PHP function inside the CI function
    $dizi = array();
    $dizi = $parametre;
    print_r(array_values($dizi))."<br>";
    echo "Tamamdır <br>";
  }
```

The code that sends an array to the PHP function. It is also inside the same above mentioned CI function:

```
} else {
    echo "... kontrol...<br>";
    echo $aday_tas."<br> code has read until here";
    acmazdami(array ($vezir_yerleri));
}
```

The code doesn't give any errors but I can't get the line

```
print_r(array_values($dizi))."<br>";
```

to work. Regards...

Comment: First step, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at top of your code.

Comment: Please also read: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631535/function-inside-a-function#answer-1631579)

Comment: How do you get `$parametre` (from database, from input form, over URL)?

Comment: Hello @Tpojka, I am getting it inside the same CI function. It is an array. I was making a logical mistake now the code is working.. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller call the method in same class with `$this->YOURMETHOD` Don't Write method inside other method

```
public function_1()// CI function
{

 //  do something

}
public function_2()//CI function
{
      $this->function_1() // to access function_1 
}
```

Comment: Functions in classes are called methods.

Comment: public function acmazdami($parametre){
$dizi = array();
$dizi = $parametre;
print_r(array_values($dizi))."<br>";
echo "Tamamdır <br>";

}

Comment: and $this->acmazdami(array ($vezir_yerleri)); Did not have any effect. There are no errors. But the code doesn't produce the result of print_r(array_values($dizi))... Not even an empty array. Regards

Comment: @Otag actually i m on mobile :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to do `$this->acmazdami(your value)`
Add `$this` before the custom PHP function.

Comment: public function acmazdami($parametre){ $dizi = array(); $dizi = $parametre; print_r(array_values($dizi))."<br>"; echo "Tamamdır <br>"; } 
 
and $this->acmazdami(array ($vezir_yerleri)); Did not have any effect. There are no errors. But the code doesn't produce the result of print_r(array_values($dizi))... Not even an empty array. Regards