# How to define local functions in PHP?

Tags: php, function

When I try to do this:

```
function a()
{
    function b() { }
}

a();
a();
```

I get `Cannot redeclare b...`.
When I tried to do this:

```
function a()
{
    if(!isset(b))
        function b() { }
}

a();
a();
```

I get `unexpected ), expected ...`.
How can I declare the function as local and to be forgotten of when `a` returns? I need the function to pass it to `array_filter`.

Comment: nesting functions is asking for a world of hurt.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Mark Elliot: The version that produced those errors is `PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2`, but this has to run on `PHP Version 5.3.6`

Comment: Did you mean "if(!function_exists('b'))" instead of "if(!isset(b))"? if(!function_exists('b')) {
        function b() { }
    } should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in your `array_filter` call.

Answer (score 9):

The idea of "local function" is also named "function inside function" or "[nested function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function)"...
The clue was in this page, [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), cited by @ceejayoz and @Nexerus, but, let's explain!

1. In PHP **only exist global scope for function declarations**;
2. **The only alternative** is to use another kind of function, the *anonymous* one.

Explaining by the examples:

1. the function `b()` in `function a(){   function b() {} return b(); }` is also global, so the declaration have the same effect as `function a(){ return b(); } function b() {}`.
2. To declare something like "a function b() in the scope of a()" the only alternative is to use not `b()` but a reference `$b()`. The syntax will be something like `function a(){    $b = function() { }; return $b();  }`

PS: is not possible in PHP to declare a "static reference", the anonymous function will be never *static*.

See also:

- [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/287948) ([ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/287948))
- [What are PHP nested functions for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415969/287948)

Answer (score 3):

**Warning for PHP 7.2 or above!**

`create_function` is deprecated in php 7.2 and removed in php 8+.

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Replaced by: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

---

**Original answer:**

You could try the `create_function` function PHP has.
http://php.net/create_function

```
$myfunc = create_function(..., ...);
array_filter(..., $myfunc(...));
unset($myfunc);
```

This method doesn't require PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 1):

You can define local function within PHP, but you can declare it only once. This can be achieved by defining and comparing static variable.

Check the following example:

```
<?php
function a()
{
  static $init = true;
  if ($init) {
    function b() { }
    $init = FALSE;
  }
}

a();
a();
```

Alternatively by checking if function already exists:

```
<?php
function a()
{
  if (!function_exists('b')) {
     function b() { }
  }
}

a();
a();
```