# nested functions in php throws an exception when the outer is called more than once

Tags: php

lest assume that i have the following

```
function a(){
  function b(){}
}
a(); //pass
a(); //error
```

why in the second call an exception is thrown and it says

```
cannot re-declare  function b()
```

i thought that each function call makes a new active record that it contains its own scope ;
like in other languages other that PHP when we declare a variable in a function and called that function all the variables are alive for their scope, why the inner function is not the same ?

Comment: Please don't add a function in a function. It is almost never needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define local functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465451/how-to-define-local-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Named functions are always global in PHP. You will therefore need to check if function B has already been created:

```
function A() {
    if (!function_exists('B')) {
        function B() {}
    }
    B();
}
```

A different solution is to use an anonymous function (this will more likely fit your needs, as the function is now stored in a variable and therefore local to the function scope of A):

```
function A() {
    $B = function() {};
    $B();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir, but a question, after calling a() the first time can we access B() globally ? as you said "Named functions are always global"

Comment: With the first method, yes. The check `if(!function_exists('B'))` just prevents the re-declaration at the second call of A. With the second method, you're able to create an unnamed function that is not global (it is stored in a variable and therefore behaves the same way as other variables do).

Answer (score 4):

This is because when you execute function `a` it declares function b. Executing it again it re-declares it. You can fix this by using `function_exists` function.

```
function a(){
  if(!function_exists('b')){
    function b(){}
  }
}
```

But what I suggest is, you should declare the function outside. NOT inside.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what is says, when you call `a()` again it tries to redeclare `b()`, declare `b()` outside of `a()` and call `b()` from within `a()` like so:

```
function a() {
  b();
}

function b() {}

a();
a();
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a function within another function like that would be considered bad practice in php. If you really need a function inside a() you should create a closure.

```
function a() {
  $b = function() {

  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're calling `a()` in a global scope. Add a [`function_exists`](http://php.net/function_exists) call to make the above code work, but really there are few scenarios where you should really do something like this.