# Nested function weirdness on PHP

Tags: php, function, nested-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nested functions in php throws an exception when the outer is called more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968031/nested-functions-in-php-throws-an-exception-when-the-outer-is-called-more-than-o)

why does

```
function foo(){
    function bar(){
    }    
}
bar();
```

return fatal error on nonexistent function  bar

while

```
function foo(){
    function bar(){
    }    
}
foo(); 
foo();
```

gives fatal error on duplicate declaration for bar()?

does php handle the function as global or in the parent's function scope?

Comment: Please see the PHP manual, it explains this very case pretty well. The manual page is here: http://php.net/manual/functions.user-defined.php , see Example #3 *Functions within functions*. - The functions even have the same name in their example!

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php#example-147)

Comment: @PeeHaa common! mine uses foo bars :P

Comment: In that case it is just a dupe :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function itself is defined at global scope, even if it was defined inside another function.  In the first case, if you don't call `foo()` before `bar()`, `bar()` will not yet exist.

You can test with [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) before creating it:

```
function foo(){
    // Don't redefine bar() if it is already defined
    if (!function_exists("bar")) {
      function bar(){
      }    
    }
}
```

However, since the nested function is *not* scoped to the outer function, the use cases for defining a function inside another function are somewhat limited.  Furthermore, it introduces some odd side-effects into your code which can become difficult to understand and maintain.  Consider if you really want to do this, and rethink your reason for doing so if necessary. You might be better served by [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) or [classes/objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) if what you're looking for is scope limits.

Answer (score 3):

Functions are *always* created in the global scope, but *only* when their definition is executed.

Comment: Can you explain what "executing a definition" means in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The function "inside" is only declared when the outer function is called.

In your first example, you don't call `foo()`, therefore `bar()` is never declared.

In your second example, you call `foo()` twice, so `bar()` is declared twice.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example,  `bar` is declared in the function `foo`.  So calling `bar` makes no sense without first calling `foo` since its definition hasn't been executed yet.  In the second example, you are calling `foo` twice so the `bar` function gets declared twice.