# Need Help Accessing a PHP Variable: Variable Scope & Globals

Tags: php, function, global-variables, scope

I'm learning about PHP and I need some help on a global variable/scope problem. I need to access the value of `$myvars` in the outer function:

```
function outer() {
   function inner($atts) {
       $myvars = $atts['mydata'];
   }
   // I need to access the value of $myvars in here:
   $jsonized = json_encode($myvars);
}

function set_atts_func($atts) {
    inner($atts);
}

add_shortcode("my_short_code", "set_atts_func");
```

I've simplified the problem as much as I can. This is part of a WordPress plugin. I've tried making `$myvars` global as follows:

```
function inner($atts) {
    global $myvars;
    $myvars = $atts['mydata'];
}
```

But, I haven't figured it out. Any suggestions?

---

Additional Info:

If someone has a better way of solving my problem than using nested functions, I'd love to hear it.

This is for a WordPress plugin for my site. In short, I need to pass the `$atts` to a javascript script.

Long Story: The `add_shortcode()` line calls `set_att_func()` and gives me access to the `$atts`. In order to pass `$atts` to the js, I'll use WordPress' `wp_localize_script()` function.

But, this function can only be called where the script parameter referenced in `wp_localize_script()` call has been enqueued in `wp_enqueue_script()`-- at least as far as I can tell. I've tried moving the `wp_localize_script()` and  `wp_enqueue_script()` calls to `set_atts_func()` without any luck. So, I'm trying to get `$atts` into `outer()`, where the `wp_localize_script()` and  `wp_enqueue_script()` calls are.

If there is a simpler and easier way to access `$atts` in `outer()`, let me know.

Comment: there is no point in defining one function insode of another

Comment: Also see the accepted answer to [What are PHP nested functions for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415969/what-are-php-nested-functions-for) - TL;DR: They have no use, so don't use them.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, Thank you for your message. I've added some additional info. If you have a suggestion or solution, I'd love to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomalak, Thank you for the link. I've added some additional info to my question. What's the best way to avoid the nested func.

Answer (score 1):

I have mostly worked on object oriented approach and in this, the variable which u want to define as global, should be declared on top of the functions definitions like this.

```
> var $x;  
function myfunc($x)  
{  
$this->x = 'dd';    
}
```

and when u will make the instance of the class u can simply call that variable x after the function myfunc() and its value will be dd. may u will have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

To make the variable global, define it at the highest (class or hierarchy) level you wish it to be accessible from, and then be sure to use the global keyword when defining it within any other function. Ex:

```
$myvas = '';
function inner($atts) {
   global $myvars;
   $myvars = $atts['mydata'];
   set_atts_func('pass argument');
}

function set_atts_func($avar) {
   global $myvars;
   // ....
}
```