# inner function can't call the variable of the outer function in php

Tags: php, variables

```
<?php

   function a(){

     $a = "hello";
      function b(){
          global $a;
          echo $a . " World";
      }
      b();
   }

   a();

?>
```

This is my code, it only echo " World" even I have use the global keyword to include the $a. Why?

Comment: This is interesting question, hovewer we should evoid nesting functions as much as possible. Why You try to declare function b inside a? Of course the question must be answered, and this is interesting, but the good practice is just not doing it :). +1 .from me.

Comment: I'm just playing around with php and find out this problem :)

Comment: OK ;). Interesting question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415969/what-are-php-nested-functions-for. I will try to figure that out. I think that global is just for the variables OUTSIDE everything. So in that case $a is local in a() contest, and that is why it is not global in b() contest :). But It is just a guess.

Comment: Does it work when you omit global $a? It looks to me like you are declaring $a within the function a(), but then in b are referencing the global $a, something different from $a within a(). I'd like to run a quick test but alas, have to reboot

Comment: @JacekKowalewski that sounds logic, lol

Comment: @BenA.Hilleli without global it won't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function a call first after call call function b. if you pass parameter in function b or set as globel $a in function a

set as globel $a in function a() because this variable use in finction b without passing parameter and set globel $a in function b because not define this variable this function

```
<?php

   function a(){
     global $a;
     $a = "hello";
      function b(){
         global $a; 
          echo $a . " World";
      }
      b();
   }

   a();
?>
```

**or you can use**

```
<?php

   function a(){

     $a = "hello";
      function b($a){

          echo $a . " World";
      }
      b($a);
   }

   a();

?>
```

Comment: What is the difference? Could you explain it more?

Comment: Yep, This is the same as declaring $a before a(). And that's why $a is global in that case, and isn't in the example in Q.

Comment: function a call first after call call function b. if you pass parameter in function b or set as globel $a in function a

Comment: Be vary careful with this answer. It radically change the semantic. Now the variable `$a` is scoped globally and accessible from outside the function `a`

Comment: And that is the answer why OP can't access `$a` in his example. His var is just not defined in the `global` namespace thus is undefined in `b`

Comment: Well it depend on the OP intention. If he want `$a` global. There some program that can output different result depending on whether`$a` being global or not.

Comment: Using global is not a good solution and I don't really understand why people agree with this solution by voting up this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell which variable from the [outer scope](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) you want to use.

```
<?php

   function a(){

     $a = "hello";
      function b() use ($a){
          echo $a . " World";
      }
      b();    }

   a();

?>
```

Comment: This is one of those questions where you see the correct answer at the bottom of the page. Let's try to fix that: +1

Answer (score 0):

please note that variables are not passed to functions by default unless otherwise specified e.g. 
use

```
function a($b){ //code }
```

**instead of just**

```
function a(){ //code }
```

I think that might be the problem you are facing.